# Replacing last x amount of numbers

Tags: php

I have a PHP variable that looks a bit like this:

```
$id = "01922312";
```

I need to replace the last two or three numbers with another character. How can I go about doing this?

**EDIT** Sorry for the confusion, basically I have the variable above, and after I'm done processing it I'd like for it to look something like this:

```
$new = "01922xxx";
```

Comment: Refine your question.  What does "replace the last two or three numbers with another character" mean?

Comment: That value is invalid. Give us useful information.

Comment: "Replace a number with a character"...?

Comment: Your variable needs to have quotes, as it's not a string without them. Basically, it's a degenerate number, as `xxx` is not a number the last time I checked ;)

Comment: @Blender: `9` is also not a valid octal digit.

Comment: @Ignacio, it could be base 9 ;)

Comment: @Blender: The digit 9 is invalid in base 9 too.

Comment: @Ignacio Not if your parser is smart enough to do modulo 9 on each digit, converting 9 => 0! Calculus does not help with Abstract Algebra too much ;)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this:

```
$new = substr($id, 0, -3) . 'xxx';
```

Result:

```
01922xxx
```

Answer (score 25):

You can use `substr_replace` to replace a substring.

```
$id = substr_replace($id, 'xxx', -3);
```

Reference:

http://php.net/substr-replace

Answer (score 2):

```
function replaceCharsInNumber($num, $chars) {
   return substr((string) $num, 0, -strlen($chars)) . $chars;
}
```

Usage:

```
$number = 5069695;
echo replaceCharsInNumber($number, 'xxx'); //5069xxx
```

See it in action here: http://codepad.org/XGyVQ1hk

Comment: Be careful of explicitly converting to a string. If the value is entered as octal and the output is also expected to be octal then this won't do as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Strings can be treated as arrays, with the characters being the keys:

```
$id = 1922312; // PHP converts 01922312 => 1 because of that leading zero. Either make it a string or remove the zero.
$id_str = strval($id);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($id_str); $i++)
{
  print($id_str[$i]);
}
```

This should output your original number. Now to do stuff with it, treat it as a normal array:

```
$id_str[count($id_str) - 1] = 'x';
$id_str[count($id_str) - 2] = 'y';
$id_str[count($id_str) - 3] = 'z';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `strval(01922312)` is `1` (not your fault; it's wrong in the question); might want to drop the leading `0` to make it clear.

Comment: Nope. I guess you can't get around it, as PHP converts it to `1` automagically!

Comment: it's not so much that it converts it to 1, it's the `$id = 019` is interpreted as octal by the parser. Just like `$id = 0x1A` is actually decimal `26`. Again, this isn't your fault; it was wrong in the question (now fixed).

Comment: Such complications just because of a leading zero... PHP is powerful, but gets annoying sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert to string and replace...

```
$stringId = $id . '';
$stringId = substr($id, 0, -2) . 'XX';
```

Answer (score -1):

We can replace specific characters in a string using `preg_replace()`. In my case, I want to replace **30** with **50** (keep the first two digits **xx30**), in the `$start_time` which is **'1030'**.

**Solution:**

```
$start_time = '1030';
$pattern    = '/(?<=\d\d)30/';
$start_time = preg_replace($pattern, '50', $start_time);

//result: 1050
```